# how to validate second control on the basis of input in first from client side

Tags: validation

I am trying to check if first text box is not empty then the following text box value must be provided.

How can I achieve this from client side?

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript. Put the following code into a function in javascript file and call that function where necessary.

`if( document.getElementById(Id-of-the-textbox1).value != null ){// then to this... }`